# Why does my application keep running?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I'm making a Whack-A-Mole game and i'm currently stuck with this problem : My game keeps running after lives are < 0 , I'm just wondering if anyone wants to take a look at my code ( the inAction boolean in particular) and can tell me what I'm doing wrong , I'm just learning :) Here is my code :

```css
#moleWorld {
  height: 330px;
  width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.field {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 21%;
  margin: 27px;
  height: 21%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: red;
}

.mole {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 21%;
  margin: 27px;
  height: 21%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
}

#generalInformation {
  height: 40px;
  width: 330px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: lightblue;
}

#level-display,
#lifes-display {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#beginEasyClick,
#beginNormalClick,
#beginHardClick {
  margin: 40px 45%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-3.1.1.js">
    "use strict";

    var currentScore = 2;
    var niveau = 0;
    var currentLives = 3;
    var inAction = false;
    var moleworld = "#moleWorld";
    var beginEasyClick = document.getElementById("beginEasyClick");
    var beginNormalClick = document.getElementById("beginNormalClick");
    var beginHardClick = document.getElementById("beginHardClick");
    var displayScore = document.getElementById("_displayScore");
    var $field = $(moleworld).find(class = "field")

    var getrandomInt(function(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min - 1)) + min
    })

    function randomField() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)
    }
  </script>


  <script>
    var moleworld = "#moleWorld";
    var $moleworld = $(moleworld);
    
    currentScore = 0;
    currentLives = 5;
    inAction = false;
    
    "use strict";
    
    $().ready(function() {

      $(beginEasyClick).click(function() {
      
          if (!inAction) {
          
            inAction = true
            
            setInterval(function() {
              spawnMole();
            }, 1400);

            showScore();
            isThisTheMole();

          }
          
        });

      function spawnMole() {
      
        var oldScore = currentScore;
        var allFields = new Array();
        allFields = document.getElementsByClassName("field")
        var target = $(allFields[Math.floor(Math.random() * allFields.length)])
        target.addClass("mole");

        setTimeout(function() {
        
          target.removeClass("mole")
          
          if (oldScore === currentScore) {
            currentLives--;
            checkLives();
          }
          showScore();
          
        }, 1000)

      }

      function showScore() {

        document.getElementById("_displayScore").innerHTML = "<span> Score : " + currentScore + " Lives : " + currentLives + "</span>"

      }

      $(beginNormalClick).click(function() {
        // $("#car").css("background-color" , "green");
        inAction = false;

      });

      function isThisTheMole() {

        $("div>div").click(function() {


          var clickedField = $(this);

          if (clickedField.hasClass("mole")) {
            currentScore++;

            clickedField.removeClass("mole");

          } else {
            currentLives--;

          }
          showScore();
          checkLives();

        })
      }


      function checkLives() {
      
        if (currentLives === 0) {
          alert("")

          inAction = false;
        }
        
      }

    });
  </script>
  
  <p id="car" class="kes">blablacar</p>
  <p class="kes">carblabla </p>
  <div id="StartMenu"></div>
  <button id="beginEasyClick"> Easy </button>
  <button id="beginNormalClick"> Normal </button>
  <button id="beginHardClick"> Hard </button>
  <div id="generalInformation">
    <p id="_displayScore"> </p>
  </div>

  <div id="moleWorld">

    <div class="field"> </div>
    <div class="field"> </div>
    <div class="field"> </div>
    <div class="field"> </div>
    <div class="field"> </div>
    <div class="field"> </div>
    <div class="field"> </div>
    <div class="field"> </div>
```

Thank you very much for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset your interval with `clearInterval()`:

```js
var currentScore = 0;
var currentLives = 0;
var inAction = false;
var interval = null;
var allFields = document.getElementsByClassName("field");

function start(lives) {
 if (inAction) {
  console.log('Already in action, ignore request');
  return;
 }
 currentScore = 0;
 currentLives = lives;
 inAction = true;
 console.log('Start interval');
 // Store interval id to be able to clear it later
 interval = setInterval(function () {
  spawnMole();
 }, 1400);

 showScore();
 isThisTheMole();
}

function stop() {
 console.log('Stop interval');
 inAction = false;
 clearInterval(interval);
}

function spawnMole() {
 var oldScore = currentScore;
 var target = $(allFields[Math.floor(Math.random() * allFields.length)]);
 target.addClass("mole");

 setTimeout(function () {
  target.removeClass("mole");
  if (oldScore === currentScore) {
   currentLives--;
   checkLives();
  }
  showScore();
 }, 1000);
}

function showScore() {
 // Use jQuery as it's already loaded
 $("#displayScore").html("<span> Score : " + currentScore + " Lives : " + currentLives + "</span>");
}

function isThisTheMole() {
 // Only listen on relevant divs
 $("div#moleWorld > div.field").click(function () {
  // Ignore click if the game is running
  if (!inAction) return;
  var clickedField = $(this);
  if (clickedField.hasClass("mole")) {
   currentScore++;
   clickedField.removeClass("mole");
  } else {
   currentLives--; // Double penalty
  }
  showScore();
  checkLives();
 })
}

function checkLives() {
 if (currentLives <= 0) { // lives could be below zero in case of double penalty
  console.log('No more lifes remaining');
  stop();
 }
}

$(function() {
 // Use jQuery as it's already loaded
 $('#beginEasyClick').click(function () {
  start(5);
 });

 $('#beginNormalClick').click(function () {
  start(2);
 });
});
```

```css
#moleWorld {
 height: 330px;
 width: 1500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.field {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 21%;
 margin: 27px;
 height: 21%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 background: red;
}

.mole {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 21%;
 margin: 27px;
 height: 21%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 background-color: green;
}

#generalInformation {
 height: 40px;
 width: 330px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: lightblue;
}

#level-display, #lifes-display {
 margin-left: 30px;
}

#beginEasyClick , #beginNormalClick, #beginHardClick {
 margin: 40px 45%; width: 70px;height: 30px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="car" class="kes">blablacar</p>
<p class="kes">carblabla </p>
<div id="StartMenu"></div>
<button id="beginEasyClick"> Easy </button>
<button id="beginNormalClick"> Normal </button>
<button id="beginHardClick"> Hard </button>
<div id="generalInformation"><p id="displayScore"></p></div>
<div id="moleWorld">
 <div class="field"> </div>
 <div class="field"> </div>
 <div class="field"> </div>
 <div class="field"> </div>
 <div class="field"> </div>
 <div class="field"> </div>
 <div class="field"> </div>
 <div class="field"> </div>
</div>
```

(I've removed some unused stuff)

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Answer (score 2):

In your code I found several mistakes. Please rewrite your code one by one.

1) For your HTML Code:
   You missed to end the  for **Id moleWorld**

```
<div id="moleWorld">
   <div class="field"> </div>
   <div class="field"> </div>
   <div class="field"> </div>
   <div class="field"> </div>
   <div class="field"> </div>
   <div class="field"> </div>
   <div class="field"> </div>
   <div class="field"> </div>
```

Correct Code will be:

```
<div id="moleWorld">
    <div class="field"> </div>
    <div class="field"> </div>
    <div class="field"> </div>
    <div class="field"> </div>
    <div class="field"> </div>
    <div class="field"> </div>
    <div class="field"> </div>
    <div class="field"> </div>
</div>
```

2) After Including the jQuery Library file you again tried to include include jQuery

Your Code was :  `<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-3.1.1.js">`

Correction Code: `<script type="text/javascript">`

3) You are trying to find the class name from id **moleWorld** but in a wrong way without semicolon **;**.

Your code was: `var $field = $(moleworld).find(class = "field")`

Correction code: `var $field = $(moleworld).find('.field');`

4) You are trying to declare a function inside of another function in a wrong way.

Your code was: `var getrandomInt(function(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min - 1)) + min
    });`

Suggested Code: `var getrandomInt = (function(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min - 1)) + min;
    });`

> Now you can use your getrandomInt variable as a function

5) your document ready method is not correct.
You wrote: `$().ready(function() {...});`

It will be: `$(document).ready(function() {...});`

> Note: Please try to use semicolon after your line end.

Run it and hope it will work now. For me it's now working.

Thanks